# Cubic Fit to Underlying Linear Model

Tags: regression, self-study

I am considering the following conceptual question from [Introduction to Statistical Learning](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/), chapter 3, number 4.

> I collect a set of data ($n$ = 100 observations) containing a single
>   predictor and a quantitative response. I then fit a linear regression
>   model to the data, as well as a separate cubic regression, i.e. $Y =
> \beta_0 + \beta_1X + \beta_2X^2 + \beta_3X^3 + \epsilon$.
>
> (a) Suppose that the true relationship between $X$ and $Y$ is linear,
>   i.e. $Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1X + \epsilon$. Consider the training residual sum of squares (RSS) for the linear regression, and also the training
>   RSS for the cubic regression. Would we expect one to be lower
>   than the other, would we expect them to be the same, or is there
>   not enough information to tell? Justify your answer.
>
> (b) Answer (a) using test rather than training RSS.

The [community around the text](https://github.com/asadoughi/stat-learning/blob/master/ch3/answers) has answered this in terms of model flexibility. The cubic polynomial makes a tighter fit against the training data and has a smaller training RSS. The overfit of the training data causes a higher test RSS.

My question is about the cubic fit on the data with an underlying linear relationship. Wouldn't a cubic regression identify the lack of importance of $X^2$ and $X^3$ as predictor variables?

I prepared some sample data to prove this for myself:

### linear fit on linear data

```
power   coeff       SE          T-stat          p-value
0       5.011958    0.038305    130.844922      4.091123238180578e-112
1       0.299021    0.002319    128.950570      1.6942879597381592e-111
```

### cubic fit on linear data

```
power   coeff       SE          T-stat          p-value
0       5.017693    0.043301    115.880040      2.9231219834217572e-105
1       0.305327    0.007315    41.739973       1.1965359594166447e-63
2       -0.000642   0.000626    1.026529        0.15361089123836455
3       0.000014    0.000014    0.982705        0.16411145023789503
```

Am I missing something in my thinking?

Comment: What was the sample size for your data? It looks like it was very large (or the error variance was very small), and if that's the case then it's not a good indication of what could happen if the sample size was 100 (or if the error variance was larger).

Comment: This was on an $n=100$. As it turned out my method for calculating the parameter standard error, t-stat, and p-value were incorrect. I was implementing this in python, but ran the analysis on R against the same generated feature and target vectors (generated nearly identically to how you did), and finally managed to get my python methods to match the R output. I have adjusted the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument is correct. Since the true relationship is linear, the square and cubic terms in the cubic fit are not significant. And that is confirmed by the large p-values (0.215 and 0.461).

As mentioned by @mark999, it seems you are using a very large sample size because the standard errors are so small. If you follow the original question and use $n=100$, the numbers would be different but the conclusion will stay the same.

```
> set.seed(1)
> x <- runif(100, 0, 5)
> y <- 5 + 2*x + rnorm(x)
> linear.fit <- lm(y ~ x)
> cubic.fit <- lm(y ~ x + I(x^2) + I(x^3))
> summary(linear.fit)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.84978 -0.56222 -0.08707  0.52427  2.51661 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  4.82067    0.20581   23.42   <2e-16 ***
x            2.06247    0.07069   29.18   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.9411 on 98 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8968,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8957 
F-statistic: 851.2 on 1 and 98 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

> summary(cubic.fit)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x + I(x^2) + I(x^3))

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.85466 -0.59246 -0.09722  0.54144  2.48360 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  4.63484    0.46455   9.977  < 2e-16 ***
x            2.42391    0.74492   3.254  0.00157 ** 
I(x^2)      -0.16671    0.34102  -0.489  0.62607    
I(x^3)       0.02144    0.04535   0.473  0.63742    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.9496 on 96 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.897,     Adjusted R-squared:  0.8938 
F-statistic: 278.7 on 3 and 96 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```